# Java Script não injeta o HTML corretamente

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Boa tarde, eu estou fazendo um site  apênas com Html5 e Css3 puro e nele tem um menu, porem eu quero que esse menu fique fixo em todas as outras paginas e então para não precisar copiar e colar o código em todas as paginas eu decidi usar um pouco de Java Script, porem ao abrir as outras paginas (sem ser o Index que foi a pagina que o menu foi feito) o browser não carrega e exibe uma mensagem de erro.

Segue abaixo a imagem do erro que está aparecendo no browser.
[image: imagem do erro que está dando]
Ao abrir o site em um servidor local ele "bulga" todo o menu e não aplica a formatação do Css que era para ocorrer, sem contar que nas outras paginas o menu nem sequer aparece.
[image: menu que está aparecendo "bulgado"]
Foto do menu como era para realmente aparecer

[image: menu original da pagina principal (Index)]
O código abaixo é referente ao menu feito em Html

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="item1 bg-color-item1">
        <ul class="texto">
            <li>
                <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="about.html">About</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="github.html">Github</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#linkedin">Linkedin</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

O codigo abaixo é referente ao menu estilizado com Css

```
     ul {
       display: flex;
       box-sizing: border-box;
       text-decoration: none;
       justify-content: space-around;
       padding: 18px 400px;  
   }

    li {
       display: inline-block;
       font-family: 'Oswald';
       padding: 5px 0px;
       }

   .bg-color-item1{
       background-color: rgb(65, 63, 63);
     }

   .item1 {
       position: fixed;
       color: aliceblue;
       border-bottom: solid 5px rgb(67, 139, 233);
       width: 100%;
     }
   a {
       text-decoration: none;
       color: #eee;
       font-size: 20px;
     }

   .item1 a {
        padding: 10px;
     }

   .item1 a:hover {
       box-sizing: border-box;
       background-color: rgb(67, 139, 233); 
       margin: 15px;
       transition: 0.5s; 
      }
```

Segue abaixo o código em Java Script

```
window.onload = function () {
var template = `
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="item1 bg-color-item1">
        <ul class="texto">
            <li>
                <a href="home.html">Home</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="about.html">About</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="github.html">Github</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#linkedin">Linkedin</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="item2"></div>
    <div class="item3"></div>
    <div class="item4"></div>

</div>
</body>
 `;

document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = template;
}
```

Obrigado desde já !

Parte do html onde eu chamo o js

```
<body>

<div id="header"></div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="main">
        <div class="flip-card">
            <div class="flip-card-inner">
                <div class="flip-card-front  giovanni">
                    <img src="img/giovanni.jpg" alt="Giovanni">
                </div>

                <div class="flip-card-back">
                    <h1 class="text-flip-card">Nome: </h1>
                    <h4 class="text-flip-card">Idade: </h4>
                    <h4 class="text-flip-card">Sexo: </h4>
                    <h4 class="text-flip-card">Estado civil: </h4>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="texto sombra-texto">
        <p>

        </p>
    </div>

</div>

<script type="module" src="./header.js"></script>
```

Comment: Na tela que vc está chamando o Menu vc tem um elemento com o ID `header`? Vc está chamando o header.js dentro do <head> ou no final do documento (digo no final do body)?

Comment: Coloque o HTML da página.

Comment: oi, desculpe esqueci de colocar a parte do html onde eu chamo o js, acabei de atualizar o codigo, Obrigado !

Comment: Existe dois pontos que você tem que levar em consideração aplicando essa abordagem.
Primeiro: sempre vai ter que ter em todas sua paginas a div com com id header
Segundo o arquivo header.js tem que está na mesma pasta do arquivo html que você esta abrindo.

Comment: @RicardoGomes eu fiz exatamente assim coloquei em todas as paginas e esta no mesmo arquivo que eu estou abrindo mas ainda sim nao funciona, vc sabe o q pode ser ?

Comment: o problema é que você está colocando a tab <body> no template, se ele irá carregar em outras páginas como menu coloque somente o código reutilizável

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Criei uma página index.html e outra index2.html e sem código algum na tag , porém só trago o arquivo menu.js. Creio ser uma possível solução para você adaptar e usar conforme deseja, lembre-se de colocar só o código reutilizável sem a tag Pai.

```js
"use strict"
const menu =`<style>
ul {
    display: flex;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding: 18px 400px;  
}

 li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Oswald';
    padding: 5px 0px;
    }

.bg-color-item1{
    background-color: rgb(65, 63, 63);
  }

.item1 {
    position: fixed;
    color: aliceblue;
    border-bottom: solid 5px rgb(67, 139, 233);
    width: 100%;
  }
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #eee;
    font-size: 20px;
  }

.item1 a {
     padding: 10px;
  }

.item1 a:hover {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: rgb(67, 139, 233); 
    margin: 15px;
    transition: 0.5s; 
   }
</style>
<div class="container">
    <div class="item1 bg-color-item1">
        <ul class="texto">
            <li>
                <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="index2.html">About</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="github.html">Github</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#linkedin">Linkedin</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="item2"></div>
    <div class="item3"></div>
    <div class="item4"></div>
    <a href="index.html">page01</a><br>
    <a href="index2.html">page02</a>
</div>`;
const bod = document.querySelector('body');
bod.innerHTML = menu;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="js/menu.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajuda !!!

Comment: Ok, a comunidade é que agradece a sua dúvida que ajudou a muitos outros, sucesso!